# How to convert a Facebook Birthday into a Java Date Object?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, date

Facebook returns me a String like:

```
06/15/1992
```

How can I convert this string date into a Java Date object?

I tried the following but it returns "Wed Jan 15 00:06:00 UTC 1992" which is not the correct date.

```
 String t = "06/15/1992";
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
 Date test = dateFormat.parse(t);
```

Comment: Read the javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat` again...

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deduct `1` from the month field , as months are indexed from `0`. So `"06/15/1992"` should be `"05/15/1992"` to get the correct result.  according to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

And use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with correct format string : `M` is for month , `m` is for minute.

```
String t = "05/15/1992";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date test = dateFormat.parse(t);
```

Comment: How do I deduct the String by 1? How do you do that?

Comment: I made two test and I figured out that January is 01 on Facebook and December is 12. So you do not need the first modification Step.

Comment: A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

Comment: And why is december number 12 on facebook and not number 11?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

instead of

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

As the SimpleDateFormat describes the meaning of letters as

> **M** : Month in year
>   **m** : Minute in hour

For more about SimpleDateFormat follow this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Why on earth do people still link documentation to Java 1.4.2?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
"MM/dd/yyyy"
```

`m` is for minute.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "06/15/1992" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
)
```

## Details

The other Answers are correct. Formatting patterns are case-sensitive. You used `mm` rather than `MM`.

## java.time

The modern approach is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "06/15/1992" , f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need MM (month), not mm (minutes).

Facebook could return dates in a different format. Here is the graph documentation:

The person's birthday. This is a fixed format string, like MM/DD/YYYY. However, people can control who can see the year they were born separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Your code should check for which date format Facebook provided you.

```
    String[] dateParts = birthday.split(birthday, "/");
    try {
        switch (dateParts.length) {
            case 2:
                // A fully formed date: MM/dd/yyyy
                Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy, Locale.US).parse(birthday));
                break;
            case 1:
                // Only a day and month: mm/dd.
                String month = dateParts[0];
                String day = dateParts[1];
                // Do something intelligent with the information.
                break;
            case 0:
                // Only a year: yyyy
                // Do something
            default:
                // Unexpected format. Give up!
                return null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getAge: Couldn't parse FB date: " + birthday, ex);
        return null;
    }
```